# Conflicting types error using linphone ios sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, ffmpeg, voip, linphone

I downloaded the linphone sdk for iphone sourcecode and compiled it on my machine. The SDK build was successful after few fixes. But while building the app in Xcode, it is throwing the following error:

Error 1:

```
/linphone-iphone/submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/src/utils/ffmpeg-priv.h:78:17: Conflicting types for 'avcodec_alloc_context3'
```

Error 2:

```
/linphone-iphone/submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/src/utils/ffmpeg-priv.h:82:5: Conflicting types for 'avcodec_open2'
```

It is coming from mediastreamer2/ffmpeg source code. Any help on how to fix this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. I am posting it here hoping it might help someone else too.

Apparently the error means that the function/method signature is already defined somewhere else (doesn't matter where it is defined). To fix this error i just renamed the function names to something else. e.g foo() to foo_old(). After doing this the compilation was successful. Ofcourse technically there is something wrong with this approach but being pragmatic it will solve the issue at hand!